# Can an Android app installed with Android studio run for several months?

Tags: android, apk

I need to deploy several instances of my app in a smartwatch. We will then give the watches to some users and we won't have access to the devices for 3 months. We won't publish the app in the play store, for which I mean, we will manually deploy the app into each of the devices (either using the IDE or distributing a compiled apk).

I remember a couple of months back, I developed an application for iOS and I noticed that after two days of inactivity I was not able to keep using the app because of "security". I just wanted to know if there is any similar restriction in Android which could prevent me from having an app running for several months without rebuilding it and re-installing it.

Comment: with my device... there are game i havent touched in days, weeks, or even months. before asking a question like this, you should have tried it yourself... youll be fine.

Comment: @DroiDev While I agree this question is somewhat unnecessary, I believe he was asking because he cannot wait around for months to see if the app stops working.

Comment: @DroiDev thanks for your advice believe me when I said I have tried it for days but as Jantzilla said, I cannot afford to test the app for a long time before actually giving it to the final users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the app is packaged and signed correctly for your method of direct installation, the app should install and continue to run on any Android device uninterrupted without any problems.

Comment: its also worth noting; if you are using 3rd party APIs and if those API changes their requirements, you might have to do the same....

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with 1) being worth noting.  Also it goes without saying that 3rd party code that's not under a devs control has the potential to change.